# Multiple log files syslogd on busybox?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, syslog

I have this project in embedded linux and using busybox + syslogd. How can I separate logs to different files depending on PID (process id). For example I have multiple running services(under development) and I want them to have a separate log files. I have read about syslog.conf, but apparently facility settings is limited to some settings like user, kern, mail, local0, etc. And there is also a syslog-startup.conf for busybox where I can set a file(single file??).

We are using busybox 1.29.3 in qemu-system-arm (vexpress-a9).

Comment: Assuming you don't want to use facilities to split out your logs, you have something of a problem. syslogd doesn't actually see the sender's PID directly. You could modify the busybox syslogd so it can parse a `[PID]` from the message (assuming it was sent with `LOG_PID`, which isn't mandatory), though.

Comment: Is there a way to do it in facilities? Sorry I'm not really familiar with this things, I'm just starting.

Comment: With facilities you can just split on e.g. local0 .. local7, possibly also news/lpr/mail (since I'm assuming your system has none of these). Otherwise you'd likely just want to add the pid support yourself as I said before and ensure your services always log with `LOG_PID` set.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now. Just need to know how my services will use the local0~local7 facility, then change the configuration on syslog.conf to have separate files.